# Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have one problem! Where is the problem? e.keyCode is unknown. I using google chrome.

```js
function Miscari(e) {
  var x = e.keyCode;
  switch (x) {
    case 37:
      dir = 'left';
      break;

    case 39:
      dir = 'right';
      break;

    case 38:
      dir = 'up';
      break;

    case 40:
      dir = 'down';
      break;
  }
  //console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: how are you calling it?

Comment: How are you calling `Miscari`?

Comment: Where is `dir` defined? Where is `dir` used? How is this called? We could use more context.

Comment: Easy guys only one have to ask how it's called

Comment: It's called in other function.

Comment: this "other" function need to pass along the event argument, `Miscari(event)` we need to see this other function too

Comment: I have one function 
http://pastebin.com/QHqNiuyj

Comment: @GemeneAdrian-Marian Please see my answer below for an explanation of how a function like yours needs to be called.

Comment: e is undefined...

Comment: Okay, but I using this document.addEventListener('keydown', Miscari);

Comment: @GemeneAdrian-Marian Please see my answer below - it does exactly what you say you want and explains why and how.

Comment: I see the problem. If i put the function Miscari outside my function Start_Game(), it works. Console shows the keys.

Comment: Of course. Functions have a private scope to them. If you have a function nested within another function, the outside world can't see the inner function.

Comment: My main function (Start_Game) it's called with button and inside is function Mutari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is running in response to a keyboard event, you will be fine because all event handling functions are automatically passed an object representing the event that invoked it and that event object contains properties that have more information about the event that took place.

In your case, your `Miscari` function was set up to receive the event via the argument `e`, but the event needs to be triggered by something for the event to be generated and passed to your function.

I have modified my code to work like you say you have your code set up, that is when the document receives a keydown. **Just activate the snippet area below with a click and then press any keys.**

```js
// This line will register the Miscari function as a keydown event handling
// function when keys are pressed down while document is in focus.
document.addEventListener('keydown', Miscari);

function Miscari(e) {
  var x = e.keyCode;
  switch (x) {
    case 37:
      dir = 'left';
      break;

    case 39:
      dir = 'right';
      break;

    case 38:
      dir = 'up';
      break;

    case 40:
      dir = 'down';
      break;
  }
  console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener that is waiting for a key down event.

```js
function Miscari(e) {
  var x = e.keyCode;
  switch (x) {
    case 37:
      dir = 'left';
      break;

    case 39:
      dir = 'right';
      break;

    case 38:
      dir = 'up';
      break;

    case 40:
      dir = 'down';
      break;
  }
  console.log(x);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', Miscari);
```

Comment: I already have that.